# Making use of passcode screen in apps. 

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm new to IOS programming - please keep that in mind.

I've come across several apps which perform some action when the wrong passcode is entered into the passcode screen.  For example some apps take a photo and do something with it. What is the best way to work with the data entered into the passcode screen?

Please note, that I am talking about the main passcode screen which the user has set themselves (not a custom passcode screen developed in the app).

Comment: vague question... be more specific..

Comment: What's vague about it? He's asking how to run some code when the wrong password is entered into the lock screen on iOS. I'm surprised that such a thing is possible, but the answer is likely to be a link to a specific part of an API reference.

Comment: Please provide a link to such an app on the appstore

Comment: Are you sure this is an application that interacts with the lock screen? It doesn't sound like something Apple would provide access to and the only reference I can find for anything like that involved [a fake lockscreen application that was pulled from the App Store](http://news.cnet.com/8301-27076_3-20071405-248/iphone-lock-screen-password-app-pulled/).

Comment: @Quentin ..you said something about wrong password in your comment...was that in his question(he referenced some apps do some stuff on wrong password..)..you have to yourself guess what will be the case..what he wants??..definitely fits vague!

Comment: @Shubhank — It is on the first line of the second paragraph of the question. Nothing vague about it.

Comment: @Shubhank — It doesn't matter *what* he wants to do, what matters is *when* he wants to it. The question is about how to listen for the wrong password event firing.

Comment: you are kind of taking his side..he is new to iOS programming..he asked for " What is the best way to work with the data entered into the passcode screen?" ... a reputed user like should have commented by saying show some code..instead you are guessing he wants to listen for wrong password...one can't tell the best way if he doesn't tell his way..

Comment: Enough guys, the person who asked this question has no real account and has only ever asked this question. It's fruitless. Just up my reply pls :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is possible, I think the apps you refer to are implementing their own passcode screens. If not, then they are probably jailbroken apps.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a lot of projects recreating the passcode screen. 
For example:
https://github.com/aporat/KKPasscodeLock

https://github.com/lashad/PTPasscodeViewController